# Vue component updating whilst typing clearing text in input

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i think this is a reactivity issue when the component is updated. Basically if I type quickly within my input and the parent data is updated the text can sometimes be lost.

Better for you to try it below, simply type quick and you will see letters disappearing.

```js
const search = Vue.component('search', {
  props: [ "suggestions", "settings", "search" ],
  template: `
  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." :value="search" @keyup="$emit('update:search', $event.target.value)">
    <p v-for="suggestion in suggestions">{{ suggestion }}</p>
  </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  data: {
    settings: {},
    state: {
      autocompletedSuggestions: []
    },
    search: ""
  },
  watch: {
    search(value) {
      const dummyData = [ 'test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5', 'test6', 'test7', 'test8' ]
      window.setTimeout(() => {
        let random = Math.round(Math.random() * (dummyData.length - 0) + 0);
        let suggestions = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < random; i++) {
          suggestions.push(dummyData[Math.round(Math.random() * (dummyData.length - 1) + 0)])
        }
        this.state.autocompletedSuggestions = suggestions
      }, 100)
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

```css
p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <search :suggestions="state.autocompletedSuggestions"
          :settings="settings"
          :search.sync="search"></search>
</div>
```

How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: You have timeout set to 100, you ca try with 10 or 1

Comment: @NikolaPavicevic This is to show the issue, in reality the timeout is an axios request...

Comment: Sorry mate, my sight is faster then the brain :) Maybe you can set some kind of debounce to wait user to type more ?

Comment: I believe this issue occurs when the Axios response returns, so a debounce wouldn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just timing issue caused by:

1. `keyup` event has a significant delay (between 50 to 80ms on my machine - depends on keyboard too I guess)
2. Very "conveniently" chosen "timeout" value for `setTimeout` in your example (if you try something significantly shorter - like 10ms - or longer like 1000ms, the chance for described misbehavior will decrease)

What happens:

1. First "a" letter typed -> event
2. `keyup` event
3. `search` updated to "a" + watcher sets timeout
4. Component updated
5. Second "a" letter typed
6. Timeout function executed updating `this.state.autocompletedSuggestions`
7. Component updated - "a" pushed as `search` prop - effectively changing value of input from "aa" to "a"
8. `keyup` event (for "aa") - but the `$event.target.value` is already set to "a"

How to fix it:

1. Don't use `keyup` event. Use `input` instead. It is fired much quicker (after user input). `keyup` is not fired when user pastes using context menu and fires for every key (including Shift, Alt etc) which is not what you want
2. Use some kind of debounce - fire the search request only after user stops typing. 400 ms works great for me. `setTimeout` used in your example to simulate ajax call is actually good for that (see my example)
3. Whenever you fire new search request, be sure to cancel previous one if there is any. Or just disable input during the request...

```js
const search = Vue.component('search', {
  props: ["suggestions", "settings", "search"],
  template: `
  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." :value="search" @keyup="onKeyup" @input="onInput">
    <p v-for="suggestion in suggestions">{{ suggestion }}</p>
  </div>
  `,
  methods: {
    onKeyup(ev) {
      console.log(`Keyup event - Value: ${ev.target.value}`)
    },
    onInput(ev) {
      console.log(`Input event - Value: ${ev.target.value}`)
      this.$emit('update:search', ev.target.value)
    }
  },
  updated() {
    console.log("Updated")
  }
})

new Vue({
  data: {
    settings: {},
    state: {
      autocompletedSuggestions: []
    },
    search: "",
    timeout: 0,
    debounceTime: 400
  },
  watch: {
    search(value) {
      console.log("Search:", value)

      clearTimeout(this.timeout) // cancel previous timeout if any
      this.timeout = window.setTimeout(async () => {
        this.state.autocompletedSuggestions = await this.getSuggestionsAsync()
        console.log("Suggestions loaded")
      }, this.debounceTime)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getSuggestionsAsync() {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const dummyData = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5', 'test6', 'test7', 'test8']

        let random = Math.round(Math.random() * (dummyData.length - 0) + 0);
        let suggestions = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < random; i++) {
          suggestions.push(dummyData[Math.round(Math.random() * (dummyData.length - 1) + 0)])
        }

        // to simulate async call
        setTimeout(() => resolve(suggestions), 100)
      })
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

```css
p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <pre>{{ search }}</pre>
  <search :suggestions="state.autocompletedSuggestions" :settings="settings" :search.sync="search"></search>
</div>
```

Comment: Simply changing it to use input worked perfect thanks! If I encounter the issue again I could add a debounce but it's fine for now.